Having an issue connecting Sennheiser PXC550 to Intel's 8265 Bluetooth
The problem description
I can't connect PXC550 again to the intel's 8265 bluetooth.  Till now it worked flawlessly for many months.  Now, probably after some update, it stopped working.
If I unpair PXC550 from my linux debian (Trixie) and redo then the pairing/trusting again it will work (even through reboots).  However, if I switch off the notebook it will not connect again (only after doing the whole procedure of unpairing and paring it again).
At first I thought that might be "new" firmware, but after I have tried older firmware the issue was exactly the same.
The error(s) I'm getting
Output from btmon:
...
> HCI Event: Simple Pairing Complete (0x36) plen 7                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              #101 [hci0] 11.658293
        Status: Authentication Failure (0x05)
        Address: 00:23:94:23:FB:B1 (Sennheiser Communications A/S)
> HCI Event: Auth Complete (0x06) plen 3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        #102 [hci0] 11.659339
        Status: Authentication Failure (0x05)
        Handle: 256 Address: 00:23:94:23:FB:B1 (Sennheiser Communications A/S)
@ MGMT Event: Authentication Failed (0x0011) plen 8                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         {0x0001} [hci0] 11.659387
        BR/EDR Address: 00:23:94:23:FB:B1 (Sennheiser Communications A/S)
        Status: Authentication Failed (0x05)
bluetoothd[1222]: = profiles/audio/avdtp.c:avdtp_connect_cb() connect to 00:23:94:23:FB:B1: Connection refused (111)                                                                                                                                                                                                                        11.765028
< HCI Command: Disconnect (0x01|0x0006) plen 3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  #103 [hci0] 13.772694
        Handle: 256 Address: 00:23:94:23:FB:B1 (Sennheiser Communications A/S)
        Reason: Remote User Terminated Connection (0x13)
...

The weird thing is that even after the successful pairing/trusting I get an error, but the connection works:
bluetoothd[1222]: = src/profile.c:ext_io_disconnected() Unable to get io data for Hands-Free Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
The HW details
Output from lshw:
*-usb:2
    description: Bluetooth wireless interface
    product: Bluetooth wireless interface
    vendor: Intel Corp.
    physical id: 7
    bus info: usb@1:7
    version: 0.10
    capabilities: bluetooth usb-2.00
    configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s

Output from inxi:
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Intel Bluetooth wireless interface driver: btusb v: 0.8 type: USB
    rev: 2.0 speed: 12 Mb/s lanes: 1 mode: 1.1 bus-ID: 1-7:5 chip-ID: 8087:0a2b
    class-ID: e001
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: down
    bt-service: enabled,running rfk-block: hardware: no software: yes
    address: <filter>
  Info: acl-mtu: 1021:4 sco-mtu: 96:6 link-policy: rswitch hold sniff
    link-mode: peripheral accept

Output from lspci -v:
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265 [Windstorm Peak]

The dmesg details
The bluetooth firmware version & revision:
[   28.286969] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[   28.292608] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-12-16.sfi
[   29.686561] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[   29.686936] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1361643 usecs
[   29.703961] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.1 build 19 week 44 2021

The whole dmesg log for bluetooth:
[   27.999028] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   27.999045] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[   27.999047] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   27.999051] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   27.999053] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   27.999057] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   28.285962] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 26 week 38 2015
[   28.286960] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 16
[   28.286963] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[   28.286964] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[   28.286966] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[   28.286968] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[   28.286969] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[   28.292608] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-12-16.sfi
[   29.554261] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   29.554265] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   29.554269] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   29.686561] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[   29.686936] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1361643 usecs
[   29.686976] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[   29.699946] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 12684 usecs
[   29.700270] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-12-16.ddc
[   29.702952] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[   29.703961] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.1 build 19 week 44 2021
[   29.705947] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading supported features failed (-16)
[   29.707324] Bluetooth: hci0: Error reading debug features
[   29.707347] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI LE Coded PHY feature bit is set, but its usage is not supported.
[   29.767302] Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
[   29.853351] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   29.853359] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   29.853364] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   29.993258] Bluetooth: hci0: Invalid link address type 1 for 22:FF:9a:1e:62:00
[   29.993264] Bluetooth: hci0: Invalid link address type 1 for 00:FF:94:23:fb:00
[   29.993266] Bluetooth: hci0: Invalid link address type 1 for 90:FF:5a:8f:8a:00
[   29.993268] Bluetooth: hci0: Invalid link address type 1 for e4:FF:e4:8c:84:00
[   29.993270] Bluetooth: hci0: Invalid link address type 1 for 48:FF:c5:85:60:00

Note: I don't know why I'm getting an error: Bluetooth: hci0: Invalid link address type 1.  I don't have anything connected yet, but these seem to be the paired devices.
The driver used is btusb
lsmod | grep bt
btusb                  86016  0
btrtl                  32768  1 btusb
btintel                69632  1 btusb
btbcm                  24576  1 btusb
btmtk                  12288  1 btusb
bluetooth            1069056  44 btrtl,btmtk,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
usbcore               401408  9 xhci_hcd,usbnet,usbhid,r8153_ecm,uvcvideo,btusb,xhci_pci,cdc_ether,r8152

My kernel version
Debian 6.10.11-1 (2024-09-22) x86_64 GNU/Linux
The bluetooth configuration (@debain Trixie)
The /etc/bluetooth/main.conf is practically stock.  Some users have reported success with changing the ControllerMode that did nothing.  I tried the  ControllerMode with values dual, bredr, le.
Tried to play around in the /etc/bluetooth/input but nothing helped. Tried these combination of parameters:
LEAutoSecurity=true/false, UserspaceHID=true/false
No change at all :/.
Does anyone have an idea how to debug it further or even better know how to fix it?
An Update:
I was running v6.10.11-1 kernel when the error propagated.

My Sony WH-1000XM3 headset cannot connect either under Debian/unstable (trixie). This issue started with the 6.10.12-amd64 kernel. With the 6.11.2-amd64 kernel, I get the "kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Invalid link address type 1" error, like you. The current workaround is to revert to a kernel older than 6.10.12. My bug report: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1083183

@vinc17 Thank you for the tip&link - so perhaps kernel regression. I'm currently running 6.10.11-1; so perhaps I would need to run even older kernel than that. Only one note my Debian Trixie is testing (debian.org/releases). I would not like to use unstable as daily driver.

@vinc17 I do confirm that it is kernel regression (thank you for the workaround).  My 6.10.11-1 is also affected.  I had to revert to 6.9.10-1 where it works.  What is weird that the error persist on reboot.  If I had phones paired with the 6.10.11-1 even rebooting back to the older kernel does not help.  You need to unpair it and pair it again...

@vinc17 you can add it as answer and I'll accept it.  I'll probably help others too.

@vinc17 I think one of these commits (from linux kernel) broke it - commit aae6b81260fd9a7224f7eb4fc440d625852245bb or
commit aae6b81260fd9a7224f7eb4fc440d625852245bb on drivers/bluetooth/btintel.c

I've added an answer. Thanks. FYI, for me, unpairing/pairing is not necessary. It is not clear whether this is a kernel bug or a bug in BlueZ (bluetoothd), which might do something incorrect (or both). If unpairing/pairing is necessary, this would at least suggest something bad with BlueZ (which maintains information under the /var/lib/bluetooth directory).

@tukan you mentioned the same commit twice.

@MariusGedminas Ah, I see. Those were issues after each other....

@tukan No, according to the fix in bluez, this is due to kernel commit 59b047bc9808. I've updated my answer to mention the fix.

This is a kernel regression. You should revert to 6.10.11-1 (this works for me, but not for the OP) or even older, such as 6.10.9-1 or 6.9.10-1 (known to work for the OP). Unpairing / pairing the headset again may be necessary.
At least 2 headsets seem to be affected: Sennheiser PXC550 and Sony WH-1000XM3.
The Debian bug I had reported: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1083183
EDIT: This matches the comments from bluez issue 973 "Unable to connect bluetooth headset after restarting bluez or rebooting" and is fixed by this commit (the cause is indeed a Linux kernel change, as explained), which is in bluez 5.78. I can confirm that I no longer have any issue with bluez 5.79 (in Debian/unstable).

@tukan Thanks for the information. I've edited my answer accordingly.

I'm having very similar issues with my Bose QC 35 II after upgrading Ubuntu 24.04 to 24.10 (kernel 6.8.0 to 6.11.0).  There's no need to un-pair from the Ubuntu side, I can make it work if I trigger pairing from the headset and then simply connect to it from Ubuntu.  My dmesg also contains "kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Invalid link address type 1 for 60:ab:d2:xx:xx:xx", which is my headset's MAC address.  The 6.8.0 kernel never showed that message.

I'm having similar issues with a Sennheiser Accentum headset after upgrading to Kubuntu 24.10 from 24.04.

Great news!  I'll get the patch in testing in few days time.

I do confirm that the new version of bluez fixes the issue for me too.
